# final_checks() on Executive module

Tags: substrateinterface

Inside `final_checks(header: &System::Header)` method

```rust
fn final_checks() {
    let new_header = <frame_system::Pallet::<System>>::finalize();
    ...
    let storage_root = new_header.state_root();
    assert!(header.state_root() == storage_root, "Storage root must match that..);
    ... 
}
```

I am not sure why `header.state_root()` and `storage_root` should be equal. As far as I know, `final_checks()` are called right after all extrinsincs are executed, which could change the state of the storage and leads to change of `state_root`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The **new** header should have the **new** storage root.

So when you are done executing the whole block, you can check that your current state root, after all extrinsics and state changes, matches what is expected by the block header. That is what is being checked here if you look carefully, and makes sense to me.

```rust
// check storage root.
let storage_root = new_header.state_root();
header.state_root().check_equal(storage_root);
assert!(header.state_root() == storage_root, "Storage root must match that calculated.");
```

Comment: Yeah I know new header has the new storage root after all extrinsincs. What I am confused is not new header, just the block header.
When block header is created, is state root calculated by predispatch? If so, then it makes sense to me.